# Can't understanding what is changing my date format from Angular to Java

Tags: java, angular, date

Im struggling understanding whats happening when I select a date from my angular calendar for example "29/05/2021" and send it to my backend it arrives as "Fri May 28 19:00:00 COT 2021" one day less.

In my calendar im setting the date timezone with pipes as utc-5 which is my timezone like this:

```
{{todo.targetDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd':'utc-5' | uppercase}}
```

when I do console.log(todo.targetDate) before sending the JSON which contains the date I can see it prints "2021-05-29" which is correct.

But when it arrives at my backend (Java) when I print I get "Fri May 28 19:00:00 COT 2021", I think the problem is im only changing the date format visually in angular, but not its value, but since the console prints the correct format in angular, im confused now.. can you plesae tell me any hint to find out the problem? Im learning front end skills so please be soft.

EDIT:
Maybe the problem is more in my backend, here is an image of how the date looks inside the JSON object which is very strange:
[image: date with strange format]

And here is my code in the backend java:

```
@PutMapping(path = "/jpa/users/{username}/todos/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Todo> updateTodo(@PathVariable String username, @PathVariable long id, @RequestBody Todo todo)
        throws ParseException {

    System.out.println(todo.getTargetDate());
    // Fri May 28 19:00:00 COT 2021
    LocalDate fechaBien = todo.getTargetDate().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC-05:00")).toLocalDate();
    System.out.println(fechaBien);
    // 2021-05-28
    // I added 1 day to make it 2021-05-29 but this is bad because then at angular it appears as 2021-05-30 XD
    fechaBien = fechaBien.plusDays(1);
    // Then I parse the localdate to Date because thats the type of this property
    todo.setTargetDate(Date.from(fechaBien.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("America/Bogota")).toInstant()));
    System.out.println(todo.getTargetDate());
    // Sat May 29 00:00:00 COT 2021
    


    return new ResponseEntity<Todo>(todo, HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

Comment: You should check the network panel of your browser to see the request that is actually sent from your frontend to your backend. This way you'll be sure which one is "not correct"

Comment: The timezone of your Java application is UTC-5. On the line is UTC-0. You parse date received from the server from UTC-5 to UTC-0 (the date pipeline do that trick in the layout template). Check the interface specification what's expected in the API and send the date in that format. It seems that the server expect that you have to send the date in UTC-5 format. 
Be aware that the date you generate on UI side are in UTC-0 format.

Comment: @ Gaël J yes thanks for the advice, I though I would find the mistake there but actually is also sending targetDate: "2021-05-29" in the json too, why it changes to one day less when it arrives?

Comment: I added java code and show how the date comes back in the json, in a strange format for me first time i see that, hope you can help me with that info

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with the date-time that your backend server is receiving from Angular. Angular is sending the date-time in UTC and your backend server is receiving the same date-time but your backend server has a timezone offset of UTC - 5 hours. The same instant is interpreted differently in different time zones e.g. `2021-05-29T00:00:00` in UTC is `2021-05-28T19:00-05:00` in your backend server's timezone.

The `java.util.Date` object (in your case, it is `todo.getTargetDate()`) is not a real date-time object like the [modern date-time types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html); rather, it represents the number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT` (or UTC). When you print an object of `java.util.Date`, its `toString` method returns the date-time in the JVM's timezone, calculated from this milliseconds value.

Note that the legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting type, `SimpleDateFormat` etc.) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**A demo using `java.time`, the modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "Fri May 28 19:00:00 COT 2021";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E [MMMM][MMM] d H:m:s zzz u", Locale.ENGLISH);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);
        System.out.println(zdt);

        // The corresponding date-time in UTC
        Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
        System.out.println(instant);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-05-28T19:00-05:00[America/Bogota]
2021-05-29T00:00:00Z
```

The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

### Your next steps:

Convert the `java.util.Date` object into `Instant` as follows:

```
Instant instant = todo.getTargetDate().toInstant();
```

Then, you can obtain the `ZonedDateTime` from it as follows:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Bogota"));
```

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: I will try what you are telling me, but im still wondering if my angular is sending the date wrong? Because if I select in the calendar 29/05/2021 why it arrives as 28/05/2021? I will carefully check what you just answer

Comment: @BugsOverflow - Your angular is sending the date in UTC and your blackened server is receiving it the same date but your blackened server has a timezone offset of UTC - 5 hours. The same instant is interpreted differenty in different time zones. `2021-05-29T00:00:00` in UTC is `2021-05-28T19:00-05:00` in your backend server's timezone. This is what I have demonstrated.

Comment: Hey I now think understand it much better, your answer I havent analyzed alot yet cause im kind on a hurry, but now I get it the date is fine, but java has utc-5 so that why it takes it like that (minus some hours), because now I told both of them to be with "utc" only, not utc-5 and now it is saving it correctly, now I need to figure out how to tell both to be in utc-5 the proper way

Comment: @BugsOverflow - I recommend you keep it in UTC. However, as I mentioned earlier there is nothing wrong with the date that is being produced and the one that is being consumed. It's just different interpretations because of different time zones. I recommend you go through my answer two-three times to grasp it fully and also switch to the modern date-time API. It just takes one step to switch and then the modern date-time API will save you hundreds of hours by virtue of its cleanliness. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt/issue.

Comment: Check your spell-checker. Only [Cajuns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cajuns) run [blackened](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackening_(cooking)) servers. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

We cannot solve your problem because you provide none of your code parsing the date string. You are not even clear about what string exactly are you sending. I can only give general guidelines.

If you only care about the date, without the time-of-day and without the time zone, parse as `java.time.LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate.parse( "2021-05-29" )
```

Never use the legacy classes `Date` or `Calendar`.